# parse js file for Java Application

Tags: javascript, java, android, rhino

I'm using `jsoup` to parse HTML from a website. There are two option lists that are dynamically created from a multidimensional array in a javascript file. Since its dynamically created `jsoup`can't parse the results in html. However, all the data I need is located in the JS file. Ideally I'd like to be able to periodically load the file and persist / refresh the array data from this file to a local database on an android application. The JS file in question is [here](http://timetables.itsligo.ie:81/js/filter.js) and the website showing the lists is [here](http://timetables.itsligo.ie:81/studentset.htm) Is there a way to download selected aspects of this file to manipulate it in Java, as you would a DOM in html?

Comment: Do you need all arrays or only specific ones?

Comment: specific ones, two of them

Comment: Still not stated which ones. Anyway, my answer covers every array, so just remove the code regarding unused ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [WebView with a JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) or you could use the [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) engine. The latter approach is described below.

First [download Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Download_Rhino) (current version is 1.7.7.1)

Copy the rhino jar (e.g. `rhino-1.7.7.1.jar`) from the lib folder to the libs folder in your android project.

Add to your build.gradle (Module: app) file the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    [other dependencies]
    compile files('libs/rhino-1.7.7.1.jar')
}
```

The following example activity loads the script file, modifies the script (see comments) and executes functions to populate the arrays. Then the arrays are retrieved and stored as arrays in java:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Function;
import org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[][] deptarray;
    String[][] zonearray;
    String[][] roomarray;
    String[][] studsetarrayByCode;
    String[][] studsetarrayByTitle;
    String[][] staffarray;
    String[][] roombydeptarray;
    String[][] modulearrayByCode;
    String[][] modulearrayByTitle;
    String[][] progarrayByCode;
    String[][] progarrayByTitle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new RetrieveJSFileTask().execute("http://timetables.itsligo.ie:81/js/filter.js");
    }


    class RetrieveJSFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line="";
                boolean store = false;

                builder.append("var deptarray;");
                builder.append("var zonearray;");

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    if(line.startsWith("var roomarray = ")||line.startsWith("var studsetarray =")||line.startsWith("var staffarray =")||line.startsWith("var roombydeptarray =")||line.startsWith("var modulearray =")||line.startsWith("var progarray =")){
                        builder.append(line);
                        continue;
                    }else if(line.contains("function PopulateFilter(strZoneOrDept, cbxFilter)")){ // populates dept and zone
                        store = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.contains("function FilterModulesByCode(Form) {") || line.contains("function FilterModulesByTitle(Form) {") ){ // populates module
                        store = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.contains("function FilterStudentSetsByCode(Form) {") || line.contains("function FilterStudentSetsByTitle(Form) {") ){ // populates studset
                        store = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.contains("function FilterRooms(Form) {") ){ // populates room
                        store = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.contains("function FilterRoomsByDept(Form) {") ){ // populates roombydept
                        store = true;
                    }
                    else if( line.contains("function FilterProgrammesByCode(Form) {") || line.contains("function FilterProgrammesByTitle(Form) {") ){ // populates prog
                        store = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.contains("function FilterStaff(Form) {") ){ // populates staff
                        store = true;
                    }
                    else if(line.contains("var zonearray") || line.contains("var deptarray") ){ // make zone and dept global
                        line = line.replace("var ", "");
                    }

                    if(store){
                        builder.append(line);
                    }

                    if( line.contains("zonearray.sort()") || line.contains("modulearray.sort();") || line.contains("studsetarray.sort();") || line.contains("roomarray.sort();") || line.contains(" roombydeptarray.sort();") || line.contains(" progarray.sort();") || line.contains("staffarray.sort();") ){
                        builder.append("return;}"); // stop function execution after population of arrays
                        store = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                in.close();
                return builder.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String jsSource) {

            if(jsSource==null) return;

            Context rhino = Context.enter();

            // Turn off optimization to make Rhino Android compatible
            rhino.setOptimizationLevel(-1);

            Scriptable scope = rhino.initStandardObjects();
            ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "javaContext", Context.javaToJS(this, scope));
            rhino.evaluateString(scope, jsSource, "ScriptAPI", 1, null);

            ((Function)scope.get("PopulateFilter", scope)).call(rhino, scope, scope, new Object[]{null,null});
            deptarray = getArray((NativeArray)scope.get("deptarray", scope));
            zonearray = getArray((NativeArray)scope.get("zonearray", scope));

            ((Function)scope.get("FilterModulesByCode", scope)).call(rhino, scope, scope, new Object[]{null});
            modulearrayByCode = getArray((NativeArray)scope.get("modulearray", scope));

            ((Function)scope.get("FilterModulesByTitle", scope)).call(rhino, scope, scope, new Object[]{null});
            modulearrayByTitle = getArray((NativeArray)scope.get("modulearray", scope));

            ((Function)scope.get("FilterStudentSetsByCode", scope)).call(rhino, scope, scope, new Object[]{null});
            studsetarrayByCode = getArray((NativeArray)scope.get("studsetarray", scope));

            ((Function)scope.get("FilterStudentSetsByTitle", scope)).call(rhino, scope, scope, new Object[]{null});
            studsetarrayByTitle = getArray((NativeArray)scope.get("studsetarray", scope));

            ((Function)scope.get("FilterRooms", scope)).call(rhino, scope, scope, new Object[]{null});
            roomarray = getArray((NativeArray)scope.get("roomarray", scope));

            ((Function)scope.get("FilterRoomsByDept", scope)).call(rhino, scope, scope, new Object[]{null});
            roombydeptarray = getArray((NativeArray)scope.get("roombydeptarray", scope));

            ((Function)scope.get("FilterProgrammesByCode", scope)).call(rhino, scope, scope, new Object[]{null});
            progarrayByCode = getArray((NativeArray)scope.get("progarray", scope));

            ((Function)scope.get("FilterProgrammesByTitle", scope)).call(rhino, scope, scope, new Object[]{null});
            progarrayByTitle = getArray((NativeArray)scope.get("progarray", scope));

            ((Function)scope.get("FilterStaff", scope)).call(rhino, scope, scope, new Object[]{null});
            staffarray = getArray((NativeArray)scope.get("staffarray", scope));

            printArray(deptarray, "deptarray");
            printArray(zonearray, "zonearray");
            printArray(modulearrayByCode, "modulearrayByCode");
            printArray(modulearrayByTitle, "modulearrayByTitle");
            printArray(studsetarrayByCode, "studsetarrayByCode");
            printArray(studsetarrayByTitle, "studsetarrayByTitle");
            printArray(roomarray, "roomarray");
            printArray(roombydeptarray, "roombydeptarray");
            printArray(progarrayByCode, "progarrayByCode");
            printArray(progarrayByTitle, "progarrayByTitle");
            printArray(staffarray, "staffarray");

            Context.exit();
        }

        private void printArray(String[][] array, String tag){
            String output = "";
            for(int row=0;row<array.length;row++){
                for(int column=0;column<array[row].length;column++){
                    output+=array[row][column]+"\n";
                }
            }
            Log.e( (tag==null?"JavaArray":tag),output);
        }

        private String[][] getArray(NativeArray nativeArray){
            String[][] javaArray = new String[nativeArray.size()][((NativeArray)nativeArray.get(0)).size()];
            for (Integer row : nativeArray.getIndexIds()) {
                for(int column=0;column<((NativeArray)nativeArray.get(row)).size();column++){
                    javaArray[row][column] = (String)((NativeArray) nativeArray.get(row)).get(column);
                }
            }
            return javaArray;
        }

    }

}
```